# ASP.NET CORE: Passing result of stored procedure to dropdown

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core and Razor pages. I have used the ADO.NET model to get data from stored procedure. I am not sure how to pass this result data to a dropdown. I am trying based on the tutorial available in https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#database.executesqlcommand , and in that the last portion - Leveraging ADO.NET via the Context.Database property.

How to pass the result of the stored procedure which contains the column "Desc" to the dropdown.

Below is the code used

```
//index.cshtml
<select class="form-control" required multiple id="selLOB" asp-for="SelectedLOBs" asp-items="Model.LOBOptions"></select>

//index.cshtml.cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;
        public IndexModel(MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public List<LOB> lOBs { get; set; } = new List<LOB>();

        [BindProperty]
        public string[] SelectedLOBs { get; set; }

        public SelectList LOBOptions { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {    
            using (var command = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXECUTE sp");
            }
        }
    }

// Model
 public class LOB
    {
         public string Desc { get; set; }       
    }

// Data
 public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
              public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
}

//startup.cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {           
            services.AddMvc();
            ConnectionString = Configuration["TestConnectionString:DatabaseConnection"]; // Get Connection String from Appsetting.json
  services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer (ConnectionString));

        }
```

Tried this new code:

```
using (var command = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "sp";
                _dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
                 using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (result.Read())
                    {
                        LOBOptions = new SelectList(result, "Desc");
                    }
                }
            }
```

but getting error as InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed

Tried below code:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {                 
            using (var command = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "sp";
                _dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();

                using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    LOB lob = new LOB();
                    lob.Desc = Convert.ToString(result["Desc"]);
                    lOBs.Add(lob);
                    LOBOptions = new SelectList(lOBs, "Desc", "Desc");

                }
            }

        }
```

and getting error in

```
lob.Desc = Convert.ToString(result["Desc"]);
```

Comment: You need to load the data coming from Stored procedure to `LOBOptions` selectList.

Comment: Hi Chetan. could you please show the code sample for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963618/how-to-populate-an-dropdownlistfor-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-4/18965261 Follow the answer for this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate an dropdownlistfor from database in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963618/how-to-populate-an-dropdownlistfor-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Hi Chethan. The await line should be set to LOBOptions ? I am not able to set to list

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` returns integer value... populating single value to SelectList is useless...  you should use `command.ExecuteReader` to get SQLDataReader with data populated from the SQL query. And then loop thru the reader to populate the SelectList. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698562/populate-dropdownlist-with-datareader-from-database)

Comment: Tried this but error: using (var command = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "sp";
                _dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
                 using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (result.Read())
                    {
                        LOBOptions = new SelectList(result, "Desc");
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed

Comment: I have added the code in original post

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Have you tried the answer [ASP.NET Core: DbSet to executing raw stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096502/asp-net-core-dbset-to-executing-raw-stored-procedure)? Do you have any issue with the answer for your previous thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core: DbSet to executing raw stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096502/asp-net-core-dbset-to-executing-raw-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate the dropdown list in the View, an object of type `SelectList` needs to be passed from server to the view. This can be passed either view ViewBag or as part of model.

An object of `SelectList` can be created by populating data into it from database. That's what you want to do.

You are simply following the answers suggested in the comments, while you also need to read about this on MSDN. You also need to read about ADO.NET too.

Nevertheless, following is the approach I suggest to populate dropdown list with data from database.

Following is the code of my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetProductCategories
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CategoryId, CategoryName FROM ProductCategory
END
GO
```

Following is my model class.

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public  SelectList Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Following is how I execute the Stored procedure from C# code and populate Categories selectList in my controller class.

```
var connectionString = "connectionString";
var productModel = new ProductModel();

List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "GetProductCategories";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        connection.Open();

        var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var item = new SelectListItem();
            item.Text = dataReader["CategoryName"].ToString();
            item.Value = dataReader["CategoryId"].ToString();
            listItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

productModel.Categories = new SelectList(listItems);
```

Comment: thanks.Now I am getting error as - Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

I can see that the connection string is fine.

But when I execute the stored procedure in SQL - I am getting 50 rows

Comment: using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    LOB lob = new LOB();
                    lob.Desc1 = Convert.ToString(result["Desc"]);
                    lOBs.Add(lob);
                    LOBOptions = new SelectList(lOBs, "Desc", "Desc");

                }

Comment: lob.Desc1 = Convert.ToString(result["Desc"]);

Comment: Seriously???? You did not notice `while` loop in my code? dude!!!! You need to iterate thru data reader to get data from it. Please read good articles on ADO.NET on MSDN.